# Facebook Login with Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am using the omniauth-facebook gem in rails 3 following the tutorial at http://blog.railsrumble.com/blog/2010/10/08/intridea-omniauth.

I am inspecting Facebook's response using

```
render :text => request.env['omniauth.auth']
```

Only the following is being returned:

```
# extra=#> info=#> provider="facebook" uid="12345678">
```

In other words, only the uid is being returned. I can't figure out why none of the other basic info is coming up for the user especially since the UID is showing up. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, happy to provide additional information, but just not sure what would be relavent here.

Comment: I figured it out. In order to see the full facebook response I used:

    auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    render :text => auth.to_xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.env['omniauth.auth']` is a hash made by Omniauth that contains all the data sent by the provider. It also contains another hash called `extra` which also contains another hash called `raw_info` - all the data sent (in this case) by Facebook's Graph API.

For example, you can access the user's email using

```
request.env['omniauth.auth']['extra']['raw_info']['email']
```

[Source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)